# Uno.dll :: Could not load file or assembly 'Uno, Version=255.255.255.255'

Tags: prism, uno-platform

Trying to reference `Windows.Devices.Geolocation` to use the `Geolocator` class from a .NET 6 core WinUI desktop head. I suspect - I am not sure - maybe the NetStandard flavor of `Uno.dll` intending to load here and that is why FileNotFoundException ?

`FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Uno, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

`<PackageReference Include="Uno.WinUI" Version="4.2.6" />`

[image]

Perhaps a little bit of WinDBG helps anything ? For me nothing.

[image: The specified module could not be found.]

What is more, it is not just a run time issue, even Visual Studio can't locate the assembly in source :

[image]

Procmon reveils, the assembly is found in the right nuget folder but the respective application process log not found:

[image]

Comment: For Windows desktop head you shouldn't need to use Uno's `Geolocator`, instead the Windows Runtime one should be used. Can you check whether the `Geolocator`'s definition comes from Uno or WinRT? This approach should be applied for Windows head - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

Comment: @MartinZikmund I intend to add Wasm head once the desktop is done and for that purpose ```Geolocator``` became available in ```Uno.WinUI``` afaik.

Comment: Yes, that is ok, you can use this class in Uno.WinUI, but for the Windows compilation, it should not be touching Uno.WinUI at all - it should use the Windows API directly. Essentially, when building Uno Platform apps, the Windows app has "no Uno layer at all", the Windows app is a plain Windows app. Can you create a simple GitHub repo which would show the issue? I can take a look and try to fix it :-)

Comment: @MartinZikmund ```Geolocator``` is located in assembly ```A```. I later wish to reference ```A``` in all heads. I compiled Prism by myself and added the .NET core flavor assemblies manually, perhaps it is a Prism issue and rather Uno related ? What shall I share with you ? Verbose runtime log and intercept a context ?

Comment: @MartinZikmund btw, just attempted to create a rep for you but the latest Uno solution template was altered in a way that it no more contains Windows Desktop head WinUI flavor ? I can see Universal Windows only. (neither Multi Platform Xamarin nor Multi Platform net6)

Comment: @MartinZikmund you reckon a .NET core trace log could help here ? ```dotnet-trace collect -- <windows.exe> arg1 arg2```
I generated one and watched with ```PerfView``` but found only the call stack , which resulted in the ```FileNotFoundException```

Comment: @MartinZikmund just pushed a rep what you requested. this is merely exhibiting what I intend to do and probably this is rather a ```Prism``` issue instead of ```Uno```. Though I keep wondering why ```Uno.dll``` is the only assembly not found. The Prism was "home-brew" and referenced there that isn't existing any longer as nuget. https://github.com/sigmarsson/72045760

Comment: @MartinZikmund ```Could not load file or assembly 'Uno.Foundation, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.``` this occurs when try to load the types from ```Uno.dll``` with the help of ```DryIoc``` ```GetLoadedTypes(this Assembly assembly)``` has that any particular  dep ?

Comment: very sorry for my late replies. I will check your repo at home. As for your last question - indeed, Uno.dll depends on Uno.Foundation.dll

Comment: Added a solution to this problem and made a PR on your repo. Sorry it took so long!

Answer (score 2):

I made a PR to your GitHub repro, but the steps needed were as follows.

First, the library had to be switched to multi-targeted by changing to `<TargetFrameworks>` in the `.csproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now the `net6.0` target is for all Uno targets and the `net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0` is specifically for WinAppSDK on Windows desktop.

Secondly, the `Uno.WinUI` needs to be referenced only on Uno targets, so:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Uno.WinUI" Version="4.2.6" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After these changes, the Windows project will no longer try to access the `Geolocator` type from `Uno.dll` and will use the proper Windows SDK Geolocator:

[image: Windows Geolocator type]